# AWS Policy Error when uploading file directly to S3 via form POST - Invalid Simple-Condition

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm getting the below error when attempting to directly POST a file from browser to S3, using a pre-authenticated token from the aws sdk

> Invalid Policy: Invalid Simple-Condition: Simple-Conditions must have
> exactly one property specified.

I have an angular app and I want the user to directly upload a file to S3, without needing to be processed by my server. I am using this as a guide https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

I'm using the aws sdk to generate the credentials and end up with something like the below, which I append to my formData and post to s3

```
Key: "e1ace7-d3c-9846-87b9-48beed3768"
Policy: "eyJleHUsoiF0aW9uIjoiMjAyMC0wNy0yOFQxNTozMzoxMFoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJLZXkiOiJlMTcxYWNlNy1kM2NjLTQ4NTgtOiOS00OGJlZWQifSx7ImJ1Y2tldCI6Imxvd3kudGVt12cG9yYXJ5LnVwbG9hEFVtcWEifSx7IlgtQW16LUFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXE1BQy1TSEEyNTYddifSx7IlgtEG16LUNyZc4WRlbnRWwiOiJBS0lBUlFMSFlHU01XM1QyVlJNVC8yMDIwMDcyOC91cy1lYXbN0LTEvczMvYXdzNF9yZXF1ZXN0In0seyJYLUFtIjoiMjAyMDA3MjhaeUMTQzMzEwWiJ9XX0="
X-Amz-Algorithm: "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256"
X-Amz-Credential: "AKIOWEI78EVR/20200728/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request"
X-Amz-Date: "20200228T112310Z"
X-Amz-Signature: "25069f754c94b5f62fd1d2e632459asd1e62a3a8430b3ef952dde64d9cb8"
bucket: "mybucketname"
```

this is then posted to `https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/` which receives the below error :(

> Invalid Policy: Invalid Simple-Condition: Simple-Conditions must have
> exactly one property specified.

My S3 bucket has CORS open per this policy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

And the IAM account I'm authorizing as has the following policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:Put*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Based on the error message that `Simple-Conditions must have exactly one property specified` I assume I just need to change my iam policy to obey but I'm not sure how? The web user should be able to upload any file directly to the S3 bucket in question...

I haven't been able to find anything in the IAM docs about what this error means exactly or how to specify one property or where. I'm sure it's a small fix somewhere I'm just not sure where. Any guesses where I can start with the simple-conditions must have exactly one property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was so close, I had to specify the key in the policy generation itself in the aws javascript sdk, whereas before I was adding it to the form from the html post side

```
  const client = new AWS.S3(options);
  const form = await client.createPresignedPost(
  {
    Bucket: bucketname,
    Fields: {
      key: guid,
    },
  });
```